# Moving folder including the running script via Git bash on Windows raises "permission denied"

Tags: windows, bash, shell, git-bash

I'm trying to rename the parent folder i'm running the script from.

I have the following (simple) tree:
`C:/workspace/FOO/Script.sh`

I'm in C:/workspace
now running `./FOO/Script.sh`

This script is just :

```
mv FOO BAR
```

I get:

```
mv: cannot move 'FOO' to 'BAR': Permission denied
```

How can I rename FOO in BAR?

Note:
*I have no issue renaming the folder with Windows GUI (aka explorer)*

Note:
*I'm looking for tricks that can be embedded in the script itself so a user won't know the difference*

Comment: how are you executing the script?

Comment: ```I'm in C:/workspace now running ./FOO/Script.sh``` =
I typed the command ```./FOO/Script.sh``` in folder ```C:/workspace``` using git-bash. What else would you need to know?

Comment: Ok, maybe not improtant but one more question is the script executable?

Comment: yes, if I run this script from FOO folder and there is a FOO folder in the first FOO folder it works. (tree workspace/FOO/FOO and workspace/FOO/Script.sh)

Comment: Does it work if you first copy the script to outside the directory tree which you are going to rename? I.e. `cp -iv ./FOO/Script.sh tmp.sh; tmp.sh; rm tmp.sh`

Comment: Running `./FOO/Script.sh` directly may mean both `FOO` and Script.sh` are locked. This may work : `source ./FOO/Script.sh` and make sure no other processes are holding FOO or Script.sh (like another terminal or notepad)

Comment: Thank you user1934428 . The issue is, I want to run the script and not run a command that calls a tmp script because I don't want the user to bother about this, I just want him to double clik on the script.
So I want to include/hide the tricks in the script itself. 
I know that a script can rename itself, means it can unlock itself... So could a script unlock also unlock its folder?

Comment: Thank you Philippe. If I put the source outside the script, it doesn't work and I don't want to add something to the script line. If I add the source in the script itself, I get a ```./FOO/Script.sh
Segmentation fault
```

Answer (score 0):

To run it from the script itself, change Script.sh to:

```
mkdir -p BAR
cp ./FOO/* ./BAR/
cp ./FOO/. ./BAR/ #to copy .git
rm -rf FOO/
```